# NetSuite - custom record field reference

Tags: netsuite

I created a custom record and un-ticked the 'include name field'. I've since done a mass import of these records. I am now referencing that custom record as a field on another record. However, the field shows the ID values of the custom record.

Ideally, I'd like to show the value of another field. I could just tick back the 'include name field' and do a mass update to fill the name but was wondering if we can reference any fields we like or must it be the 'name' field only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the 'include name field' is ticked, the user is required to populate that field and once the custom record has been saved and referenced to other record, you will see that name.

However if it is unticked, the user will not be required to set the name but upon saving the custom record, the name will be set with its internal id and that is native. That is why you are seeing its internal id when referenced to other record.

If you dont want the user to set that name, you might need a customization to properly populate the name. Either suitescript or suiteflow.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if we could specify a field to use rather than the name. I guess we can the name in customisation. Thanks.